# A kind of $p$-ellipticity

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

It's well know that a matrix $A(x)$ is unniformly elliptic if
\begin{equation}
\langle A(x)\xi,\xi \rangle \ge \lambda |\xi |^2
\end{equation}
for some $\lambda > 0$. I'm wondering if there is a kind of $p$-ellipticity such that
\begin{equation}
\langle A(x)|\xi|^{p-2} \xi,\xi \rangle \ge \lambda |\xi |^p.
\end{equation}
More precisely, I'm asking if it is possible to exibit matrices satisfying the condition above and better yet for all $p$. My ask is motiveted by an study of $p$-harmonic functions. I do not want to work a empty set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\xi|^{p-2}$ is just a number, every matrix that is uniformly elliptic will also trivially be "$p$-elliptic".

Answer (score 1):

You can look up [DiBenedetto](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0362546X83900615) or [Mingione](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00205-002-0231-8) and the references there, for example. The authors introduce notions of "$p$-ellipticity" and prove some regularity theorems for more general classes of differential operators (including $p$-Laplace operator).